# Java creating image from inputStream

Tags: java, image, grails, javax.imageio

I am creating the image from inputStream and I have used two methods but both the methods fails.

1st Method:

```
FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(file)
byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
int length = 0;
while ((stream != null) && ((length = stream.read(byteBuffer)) != -1)){
out.write(byteBuffer,0,length);
}
out.flush()
out.close();
stream.close();
```

This method generates the image but while trying to open it. It says "**This is not a valid bitmap file**".

And the 2nd method:

```
BufferedImage imBuff = ImageIO.read(stream);
ImageIO.write(imBuff, 'png', file);
```

And this one generates the exception.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
>           at javax.imageio.ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromRenderedImage(ImageTypeSpe
>   cifier.java:925)
>           at javax.imageio.ImageIO.getWriter(ImageIO.java:1591)
>           at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1520)
>           at com.k12report.frontend.ClientAuthoringController$$EOU2Lt2o.getImages(
>   ClientAuthoringController.groovy:55)
>           at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(Pag
>   eFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
>           at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter
>   .java:63)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
>   java:1145)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
>   .java:615)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thanks

Comment: What is `stream`?  What is it's contents?  Have you tried dumping the contents to disk and verifying it's validity through an external image program?

Comment: stream = response.getEntityInputStream()

Comment: Are you sure you have a valid image to begin with? In the 2nd method, `imBuff` is `null`, this happens when ImageIO don't recognize the file format. You need to test for that situation. Your 1st method looks good to me. You should probably check for `stream != null` outside the loop for readability and performance though.

Comment: who said: **This is not a valid bitmap file**? (this is not clear to me...)

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the **this is not a valid bitmap file**

Using File.separator is the more recommended way instead of using "\" or "/" if you are using file paths as they depend on OS.They make your code more portable.

Example:-

`File f = new File("C:"+File.separator+"Personal"+File.separator+"test.bmp");`

Comment: I am using grails so,

`def root = getServletContext().getRealPath("");
String path = root+'/authoringImages/'+images
File file = new File(path);`

Comment: for me, using **/** as file separator works **always** (when working with File-Object)...also when using windows....